# Yii2 Codeception test of API endpoint that expects JSON POST

Tags: php, yii2, codeception

Does anyone have any experience of using Codeception tests within Yii2 to test an API endpoint that expects a JSON request?

Right now, I'm just hoping to do a basic check for a 200 response code and a JSON body.

Currently, my test breaks with "[PHPUnit_Framework_ExceptionWrapper] Bad request."

Edit
It turns out this 'Bad request' error is thrown by my own code, because the $request->getRawBody() is empty. That is, the parameters that I have set in the call to sendPOST() are not making it through into the Yii request object. Without them present, the request is doomed to fail.
/Edit

Edit2
Remove headers from the test (as per comments) and it works.
/Edit2

I'm trying to use the sendPOST() method of the Codeception REST module.

I'm not confident that Codeception\Lib\Connector\Yii2.php is correctly mapping my parameter data from the BrowserKit Request to the corresponding Yii Request. That is, the request that goes into doRequest() has my data, but $app->getRequest() later in that same function lacks it.

Here's my test:

```
$I = new FunctionalTester($scenario);
$I->haveHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); //remove
$I->haveHttpHeader('Accept', 'application/json'); //remove
$I->sendPost(
    '/index-test.php/api/v1/poi/bbox',
    [
        'bbox' => [
            'minLat' => 51.53667954545721,
            'minLng' => -0.14273375272750854,
            'maxLat' => 51.53749870786214,
            'maxLng' => -0.13856828212738037
        ]
    ]
);
$I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
$I->seeResponseIsJson();
```

And here's a CURL representation of a working request:

```
curl \
--request POST \
--header "Accept: application/json" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" \
--data '{ "bbox": {"minLng": -0.152573, "minLat": 51.529012, "maxLng": -0.124691, "maxLat": 51.54104} }' \
<endpoint>
```

Did I do something wrong at an earlier stage? Or, am I approaching this the wrong way? Perhaps there's a better way to send a JSON POST request like this?

Comment: have you tried running `codecept run functional` with `--debug` flag? that will show you what is being sent and the headers. I take for granted that you're using the REST module for CodeCeption.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am using the debug flag to codecept - it's that which is showing me the "[PHPUnit_Framework_ExceptionWrapper] Bad request." I have some additional information relating to this, which i shall add to my original post.